# Error handling property type

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` and when this happens I would like to return null.

does anyone know the best way of doing this?

```
 const currenFolderId = this.state.currentFolder.id
    ? this.state.currentFolder.id
    : null;
```

Comment: When you have a chained access like `this.state.currentFolder.id` it will fail with that error if a property in the chain doesn't exist: `this.state.currentFolder = undefined; console.log(this.state.currentFolder.id); // TypeError!`

Comment: thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
const currenFolderId = this.state.currentFolder && this.state.currentFolder.id
   ? this.state.currentFolder.id
   : null;
```

Comment: this works.I dont understand why you need to do this.state.currentfolder&& .

Comment: With `this.state.currentFolder` you check if `currentFolder` is not `undefined` - then if `currentFolder` has `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentFolderId = null;

if (this.state && this.state.currentFolder) {
    currentFolderId = this.state.currentFolder.id ? this.state.currentFolder.id : null
}
```